# Script To Logout Root and Login User

Tags: 12.04, scripts, users, root

I was wondering if there was a way to make a script that logouts of root or takes the automatic root login and logs in a user.  This is for security reason so that the user cannot change important files.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 or a EMB-3500 freescale board(i.mx6 chip)(ARM).

Note*  I do not have a bootloader or inittab file.  My opening console that logs in as root is ttymxc0 which is specific to the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try:
su -l user;exit;

That would switch to the user, then drop the root session if the user logs out.